# Wordpress cropping/scaling images

Tags: php, wordpress, function, image-scaling

I am setting up a affiliate website using Wordpress. From each affiliate I import product images. The images all have different sizes.

In the functions.php file the following default code is used:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 848, 477, false )
if (function_exists('add_image_size')){
add_image_size( 'compare-shop-logo', 150 );
add_image_size( 'compare-single-product-2', 240, 188 , false );
add_image_size( 'compare-slider-image', 848, 487, false );
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 400, 300, false );
add_image_size( 'compare-blog-box', 400, 225, false);
add_image_size( 'compare-quote-box', 408, 437, false );
```

Now some images are not scalled properly. I tried changing the dimensions and changed the option from 'crop' to 'scale' (and regenerate the images). Inspite of this I can not get the propartionality right.

For example:

On my homepage www.prijsvergelijk.outdoorinfo.nl you'll see the product "Deuter Zugspitze 24" (the blue one) see also screenshot --- http://prntscr.com/cplfgs .

The proportions of this image is not correct. When the product is clicked the orignal image is displayed and these proportions are right. In fact, the images shown here is the Original image.

Anyone an idea?

http://prijsvergelijk.outdoorinfo.nl/product/deuter-zugspitze-24-2/

Comment: Setting sizes of different proportional images is not very handy, the best you could do is provide the ability to set the image size from backed to generate thumbnails accordingly.
[This plugin might help](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/)

Comment: I see that for your image you have set height and width as 100%. change that to max-width: 100% and height: auto. And it will maintain the proportion.

Comment: Thanks for the hint guys. Both solutions work! Small addiotional question. I can't seem to vertical align the images in the box. What am I missing?